# How to remove wasp paper from soffit vents and siding

Tags: cleaning, pest-control

Paper wasps built a huge nest under the second-story eave shown below (photo taken looking straight up).  I killed and scraped off the nest, but there is still paper-like residue clinging to the vinyl soffit vents and cement-board siding.

How can I remove the residual wasp paper?

[image: Paper wasp nest residue]

Answer (score 1):

We won't read about your house burning down as a result of using fire, will we? It was my first instinct to suggest fire as an answer, but it's really not a good one. A pressure washer would not be advised, due to water getting in the worst place, insulation!

That leaves high pressure air, from a compressor, as a possible solution. It's certainly less damaging than a pressure washer and will not cause insulation problems either. Combine a stiff brush with the high pressure air flow and you'll have a decent result.